# Nested relationships in Kohana 3 ORM

Tags: php, orm, kohana, kohana-3, relationships

Let's say I have three ORM models in Kohana.

```
class Model_Category extends ORM
{
    protected $_has_many = array(
        'groups'      => array(
            'model'       => 'group',
            'foreign_key' => 'category_id'
        )
    );
}

class Model_Group extends ORM
{
    protected $_has_many = array(
        'users'      => array(
            'model'       => 'user',
            'foreign_key' => 'group_id'
        )
    );
}

class Model_User extends ORM
{

}
```

I would get all the groups in a category by calling `ORM::factory('category')->find($id)->groups`. I would find all the users in a group by calling `ORM::factory('group')->find($id)->users`. How would I find all the users in a category?

Comment: By finding all category groups and then finding all users in those groups.

Answer (score 1):

I would find all the users in a group by callin

```
 $groups = ORM::factory('category', array('id', $id))->groups->find_all();
```

How would I find all the users in a category?

```
 ORM::factory('group', array('id', $id))->users->find_all();
```

Comment: if `id` is primary key, it's enough to call `ORM::factory('category', $id)`

Answer (score 1):

You'll be able to use `ORM::factory('category', $id)->users->find_all()` after adding a has many *through* relationship:

```
class Model_Category extends ORM
{
    protected $_has_many = array(
        'users' => array('through' => 'groups'),
        // ...
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Find all the groups in a category

```
$groups = ORM::factory('category', $id)->groups->find_all();
```

Iterate over the groups and get her user

```
foreach ($groups as $group) 
{
  $users = $group->users->find_all()
}
```

Or build a join, like this

```
 $users = DB::select('users.*')->from('categories')
     ->join('groups', 'LEFT')
     ->on('categories.id', '=', 'groups.category_id')
     ->join('users', 'LEFT')
     ->on('groups.id', '=', 'users.group_id')
     ->where('categories.id', '=', $id)
     ->execute();
```